# Login with Nativescript and Prestashop

Tags: php, web-services, connection, prestashop, nativescript

I have a shop APP with Prestashop connection and developed in Android Studio, but I need to make an hybrid APP, in this case with Nativescript. To create the layouts and style is all great but I don't know How to make a connection with webservices.

In my first APP to Post the values I have:

```
new AuthentificationTask().execute(Config.LOGIN_URL + "&email=" + Login.getText().toString() + "&passwd=" + PassWord.getText().toString());
```

And in the PHP:

```
if(Tools::getValue("boutique") && Tools::getValue("email") && Tools::getValue("passwd"))
{
Shop::setIdShop(Tools::getValue('boutique'));
$cntxt =  Context::getContext();
$cntxt->shop = new Shop(Tools::getValue('boutique'));
if(Tools::getValue("email"))
{
    if (!Validate::isEmail(Tools::getValue("email")))
        echo json_encode(array('valide' => 0));
    $customer = New Customer();
    //$customerExists = Customer::customerExists(Tools::getValue("email") , true);
    $customer = $customer->getByEmail(Tools::getValue("email") ,Tools::getValue("passwd"));

        if (@$customer->active) {
            echo json_encode(array('valide' => 1,'id' => $customer->id));           
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array('valide' => 0));         
        }
}else{
        echo json_encode(array('valide' => 0));
}
}
```

It's all OK, I get the value valide (1,0).

Now with Nativescript, I don't know, How I can pass the values, I write this code:

```
viewModel.login = function() {
    return fetchModule.fetch(config.url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            boutique: 18,
            email: viewModel.get("email") ,
            passwd: viewModel.get("passwd"),

        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

    })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('NO');
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(r => { return r.json(); }).then(function (r) {

        //var Valide = ResponceObject.getInt("valide") ;
         console.log('SI'+result);
        config.token = data.Result.access_token;
    });
};
```

I really need your help.

Comment: I don't get it, you want to get logged in on Prestashop right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Let me get this straight: your app is in NativeScript and you want people to be able to log into Prestashop from there correct? Do you then want them to be redirected there too or just get somekind of token to be used on Prestashop?

Comment: The people log like client, and Prestashop will send the list of products. Then the client will have the option to send a list with the products. But I don't know, How can I POST/GET with Nativescript.

Comment: I'm proficient on Prestashop not NativeScript sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd suggest using the http module and not fetch for this

Comment: Yes, with http module works fine. Thanks